# Use Python to combine excel files from folder and keep the original formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, format

I have already searched for the problem on the Internet, but no satisfying solution.

Lots of excel files that have different formatting in one folder.

The requirement is that combining all the excel files into different sheets of 1 excel. And the sheet name should be the individual excel name, meanwhile, it should keep the original formatting of each excel.

I now can use **Pandas** to combine all the excels, but the formatting is changed after writing to excel.

***How to keep the formatting including the font, alignment, background and etc? Any suggestions? Thanks.***

```
import pandas as pd
import os


# 1, List excel files:
path = r'C:\Users\h290602\Desktop\SAP'
files = os.listdir(path)

#2, Pick excel files
files_xls = [f for f in files if f.endswith(".xlsx") or f.endswith(".xls")]


#3, Initialize a empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()


#4, Loop over the list of files to empty dataframe

save_path = '{0}\{1}.xlsx'.format(path,'results')
result = pd.ExcelWriter(save_path)

for  f in files_xls:
    excel_file_name  = f.split('.')[0]
    if '~$' in f: 
        f = f.replace('~$','')
    excel_path = '{0}\{1}'.format(path,f)
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
    df.to_excel(result,excel_file_name,index= False)

result.save()
```

Comment: have a look at [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) it can help you copy fonts, border, alignment,... pandas deals only with the raw data

Comment: yes, but I only want an easy method to deal with the format. Keep the original.